# Dynamically Adding Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create a plugin folder that will have various plugins. So, for example if there is a plugin called "admin", there would be a /plugins/admin folder which would have a adminOnly file that looks something like this:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {...})
router.get('/link1', (req, res, next) => {...})
router.post('/link2', (req, res, next) => {...})
router.get('/link3', (req, res, next) => {...})
.
.
.
```

Previously, in my app.js file I have something like:

```
const adminOnly = require('.../plugins/admin/adminOnly'
...  
app.use('/adminOnly', adminOnly)
```

This results in if i go to www.website.com/adminOnly/link1 I get whatever is in the router.get for link 1.

However, I want to make it all dynamic so that I can change my app.js logic so that it is something like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const possiblePlugin = require('.../plugins/${req.baseUrl}')
  res.render<or something> (possiblePath)
}
```

The idea is to attempt to go to a path that the front end requests and see what is there but to dynamically add the paths at runtime so anyone can add plugins whenever and they work.

Comment: I'm sure you are aware of this, but take care to sanitize the input so that users aren't able to request unexpected files (e.g. `../../../etc/passwd`)

Comment: My actual idea was to only let users access .../plugins/nameOfPlugin/index.js and then require all plugins maintain the route to be named index.js

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder for every route. So your file system would be like this:

```
/plugins
-><name of plugin>/
---->index.js
---->otherFilesNeededForThisPlugin.js
```

Secondly, instead of searching for the route once someone requests it, it makes more sense to add all the routes when you start the server. So, you can read all the folders in /plugins and then for each one add there index.js file. Something like this:

```
// adds all plugins. Plugins should be in the 'plugins' folder
// and the route should be named 'index.js'
fs.readdirSync(join(__dirname, 'plugins')).forEach((fileOrFolder) => {
  const fullFilePath = join(__dirname, 'plugins', fileOrFolder);
  if (fs.lstatSync(fullFilePath).isDirectory() && fs.existsSync(`${fullFilePath}/index.js`)) {
    const pluginName = `/${fileOrFolder}`;
    const pluginModule = require(fullFilePath); // eslint-disable-line
    app.use(pluginName, pluginModule);
  }
});
```